# GridView onclick not working with on touch

Tags: android, android-gridview, android-gesture

I have implemented a grid view in my application. for refreshing the grid i have given touch event to it. and in on click I do some stuff with that grid item. below is the code for gesture detector -

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

public OnSwipeTouchListener(Context ctx) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ctx, new GestureListener());
}

private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 300;// make it 100 if down
                                                    // swipe is not working
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
            float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD
                        && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }

    // @Override
    // public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
    // onClick(); // my method
    // return super.onSingleTapConfirmed(e);
    // }

}

public void onSwipeRight() {
}

public void onSwipeLeft() {
}

public void onSwipeTop() {
}

public void onSwipeBottom() {
}

// public void onClick() {
// }

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
}
}
```

and below is the touch and click listeners on grid view -

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                        }
    });

 gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(
            MidnightMainActivity.this) {
        public void onSwipeBottom() {
            gridView.startAnimation(slidedown);
            inflateHomeLayout(MODE_REFRESH);

        }

    });
```

now touch is working but on click detects another item instead of clicked one. How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you return true value in onDown function? Are you sure you handle this event? Try to return false.

Comment: Great, I've add above comment as answer to your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To respect StackOverflow question - answer flow, I place my answer here:

> Why are you return true value in onDown function? Are you sure you handle this event? Try to return false.

Answer (score 0):

Return false from onDown function, It may be working.

```
@Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate of the other answer